# How do I extract time out of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
const string = 'Member has a training (30 Minutes) appointment at 12:00 AM'
```

Is it possible somehow to extract the time out of this string so that it returns something like this:

```
'12:00 AM'
```

So far I've tried something like

```
string.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '')
```

But it will also leave in the `'(30)'` from `'(30 Minutes)'`. Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const string = 'Member has a training (30 Minutes) appointment at 12:00 AM'

document.write(string.match(/[01]?\d:[0-5]\d ?[AaPp][Mm]/))
```

**Regular Expression Explanation:**

```
[01]? -- starts with an optional 0 or 1
\d    -- followed by any digit 0-9
:     -- followed by a colon
[0-5] -- followed by any digit 0-5
\d    -- followed by any digit 0-9
 ?    -- followed by an optional space
[AaPp][Mm] -- followed by AM or PM (or am or pm)
```

Comment: Did you look mine over at all? It's faster than regex.

Comment: @shadoe2020 Yours assumes the time is always at the end of the string and it assumes that the time is always 9 characters. The regex is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

**.substring();** -

> "returns a portion of the string, starting at the specified index and
>   extending for a given number of characters afterward."

```
const string = 'Member has a training (30 Minutes) appointment at 12:00 AM'
test = string.substring(50,59)
```

**.slice();** -

> "The slice() method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a
>   new string, without modifying the original string."

```
test = string.slice(50)
```

-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr
-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

---

Code Snip

```js
const string = 'Member has a training (30 Minutes) appointment at 12:00 AM'

function sliceIt(){
let slice1 = string.substring(50,59);
document.getElementById('slice').innerHTML = slice1;
}

function subStrIt(){
let substr1 = string.slice(50);
document.getElementById('substr').innerHTML = substr1;
}
```

```html
Extracting time out of "Member has a training (30 Minutes) appointment at 12:00 AM"<hr><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Slice" onclick="sliceIt();" \><input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="Substr" onclick="subStrIt();" \>
<hr>
Example of slice:
<span id="slice"></span>
<br><br>
Example of substr
<span id="substr"></span>
```

Comment: This only works if the format is constant. Even a simple space at the end of the `string` will break it. Or if the the Member's name changes or its 5 minutes. `Sam has a training (5 Minutes) appointment at 12:00 AM `

Comment: Unless you get the length of the string and add logic to accomodate that. Regardless this does the job, and answers the question.